# user role to run replSetGetStatus command in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to run the below command to get my replica set status. But I am getting the follwing error:

```
db.adminCommand({replSetGetStatus: 1})
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetStatus: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13
}
```

Here is my user document in db.system.users collection

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.prodDb",
    "user" : "prodDb",
    "db" : "admin",
    "credentials" : {
        "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
            "iterationCount" : 10000,
            "salt" : "okdfd74YA3/mTiSad2+zjS4Ag==",
            "storedKey" : "aoCDvsdfh+asvbGajSinnUvXaqc08=",
            "serverKey" : "kdc6B3LgvrNE4gT1CsBEzEvDCadms="
        }
    },
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "XXXX"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "XXXX"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "XXXX"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "XXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

I then tried to give read access to the admin db by doing this -

```
db.system.users.update({'user': 'prodDb'}, {$push: {"roles": {"role": "read", "db": "admin"}}})
```

I also changed the role from `read` to `readWrite` but same problem persists. I don't want to provide `admin` rights to this user. What should I do.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User should have `clusterManager` role: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterManager

Comment: clusterMonitor is the right user-role as it provides read-only access to monitoring tools. Thanks anyways.